# how to find polynominal equation with roots and canonical form

Tags: polynomials

### Problem

I had to solve a math problem that looks like this:
Find the polynomial equation of degree $2$ for which the roots are $0$ and $4$ and the canonical form is $a(x - 2)^2 + 3.$

Then i got stuck in this equation and couldn't go any further:

> $a(x - 2)^2 + 3 = a(x(x-4))$
>
> $a(x^2 - 4x + 4) + 3 = a(x^2+4x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug the roots in the canonical form:

$$a(0-2)^2+3=a(4-2)^2+3=0$$

and solve for $a$.

Even though there is a single parameter but two conditions, there is a solution.